# SQL Server 2008: How to Copy Data from Table in DB1 to Table in DB2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two identical databases on the same server. During a deployment process, I have data in tables in database A that need copied over to the tables in database B. What is the easiest way to programmatically accomplish this task?

EDIT:

- Tables do have identity columns.
- There are tables with foreign key constraints, so insert order is important.
- All of the rows will need to be copied. As far as I'm aware, this will always be the case.

Comment: Any identity columns to take into consideration? Is insert order important to satisfy foreign key constraints? Are you copying the whole table or only certain rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the tables don't have identity columns and belongs to the default (dbo) schema, try the TSQL insert query below;

```
Insert Into DatabaseB.dbo.DestinationTable
Select * From DatabaseA.dbo.SourceTable
```

If you have an identity column then execute statements below

```
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT DatabaseB.dbo.DestinationTable ON
GO

        Insert Into DatabaseB.dbo.DestinationTable
        Select * From DatabaseA.dbo.SourceTable
GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT DatabaseB.dbo.DestinationTable OFF
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

If the databases are in different servers:

```
exec sp_addlinkedserver ServerA

Insert Into DatabaseB.dbo.DestinationTable
Select * From ServerA.DatabaseA.dbo.SourceTable
```